# Totally unresponsive card with RFID-RC522 Module

Tags: rfid

I bought an RFID-RC522 module including two attached PICC cards: a blue key chain tag and a white card with the type of MIFARE 1KB. In addition, I bought two other separate cards from the same seller.
I connected the module to an Arduino board and ran some examples of the library MFRC522.

Everything was OK with the two attached PICC cards (blue tag, and white card), BUT NOTHING worked with the other two cards, even they have no UID and NEVER RESPOND to the module. It seems to me that the internal microcontroller is not programmed. The seller doesn’t have any explanation. So, I need to know how to make them work.

Comment: so, the card you bought separately don't work ... are they 125KHz or 13.56MHz rfid? because they do look the same, but the MFRC522 only with one of those frequencies

Comment: Do you think that the cards bought separately are of the frequency 125KHz, so they don't respond to 13.56MHz  MFRC522 ?